# Input impedance of the op-amp inverting amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance

I have a lab exercise with inverting opamp (gain = 10, R1 = 1k, R2 = 10k). The subject of the lab is to measure input impedance of such amplifier by adding 1k resistor in series to the input and drive it with 1kHz sine wave.
Could someone explain what should I measure and how to calculate impedance in such case?

EDIT: Uploaded part of textbook
[image]

Comment: If the input impedance were (say) 2 kohm, and the source was 1 volt RMS, what voltage could you expect to measure across the added 1 kohm series resistor?

Comment: Added picture with textbook about that exercise. Why -1?

Comment: Probably because it's homework but you didn't show any attempt to solve it.

Comment: That's not homework. Something I'm doing after hours... and simply don't understand

Comment: Maybe it would help if you explained what you do understand about it. Then it's easier to explain what went wrong.

Comment: My understanding was input impedance here is equal to 1k because of virtual ground. If I add some series resistance Rx to input, then input impedance is simply a sum of 1k + Rx. 
As I think about it more, is an additional series resistance required to measure input current?

Comment: An additional series resistor is only needed to measure input impedance if you don't have an ammeter.

Comment: *My understanding was input impedance here is equal to 1k because of virtual ground.* That is correct. Now suppose you feed a signal to this circuit **via a 1 kohm series resistor**. What should the signal amplitudes be, assuming the input impedance is indeed 1 kohm?

Comment: Ok I thought there's something more complicated under this... really? That's it?! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you put a 1k resistor in the input and drive that with a signal from your function generator, then the voltage across this resistor will give the current that goes into the input of the circuit, so you can calculate its input impedance.

[image]

Of course since the resistor is not referenced to ground you will need a differential probe that can measure a voltage difference between two points, not just a scope probe that can only measure the voltage between one point and the scope ground, which is normally connected to Earth on most scopes.

Ironically it is much easier to measure the output impedance, connect the input to ground so it outputs 0V, inject a current in the output with a function generator and a resistor, and you don't need a differential probe to measure the voltage at the output. It will be very low, but most digital scopes have an "average" button this day. If that's not enough, borrow someone else's opamp to amplify it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Vin---[node.a]---R(1k)---[node.b]---Z(amplifier input)---GND

First off, redraw the circuit to basic elements to avoid confusion (I'm too lazy to do real art, so I gave you text art). Once you are adept at this simplification, you can do it in your head.

You use Ohm's law.
Measure the voltages at node.a=Vin and node.b.

Calculate the current flowing through R(1k) (the reference resistor added in series with the input).

Since you now know the voltage at node.b and the current flowing in to R(1k) which is the same current flowing in to Z, you can calculate Z (amplifier input impedance).